# Zip method fails in creating a dictionary when a mix of foreign languages are used

Tags: python, dictionary

I've two lists that I'm trying to combine into a dictionary via the zip method with the aim to do some text analysis.
The final output is however compromised by the time an item with a foreign language - I'd say Arabic - is found in the list.

See a compromised extract of my two lists:

```
['virus',
 'corona',
 'health',
 'like',
 'forever',
 'must',
 '10000',
 'claim',
 'ensured',
 'have',
 'wealth',
 'cities',
 'way',
 'chickens',
 'get',
 'straight',
 'amp',
 'fighting',
 'please',
 'shit',
 'me',
 'still',
 'cases',
 'pandemic',
 'pregnancies',
 'teenage',
 'wrong',
 'ziko',
 'lockdown',
 'cancel',
 'exams',
 'self',
 'wearing',
 'because',
 'harder',
 'hit',
 'mad',
 'racis',
 'going',
 'labour',
 'minister',
 'plant',
 'said',
 'saplings',
 'state',
 'vanish',
 'fight',
 'coronavirus',
 'curfew',
 'ma',
 'needs',
 'quite',
 'thinking',
 'unnecessary',
 'periodcorona',
 'traced',
 'real',
 'behind',
 'dumb',
 'hahaha',
 'joke',
 'long',
 'spent',
 'twist',
 'worst',
 'tested',
 'children',
 'exposed',
 'gassed',
 'missing',
 'pee',
 'raped',
 'sitting',
 'staff',
 'theyre',
 'again',
 'spread',
 'baits',
 'ignored',
 'many',
 'mocki',
 'tantrums',
 'threw',
 'free',
 'may',
 'people',
 'let',
 'odd',
 'rally',
 'spike',
 'suddenly',
 'cancelcbseboardexams2020',
 'depression',
 'baker',
 'bun',
 'looking',
 'mother',
 'ntonntoni',
 'oven',
 'son',
 'threads',
 'wat',
 'got',
 'three',
 'brother',
 'give',
 'patients',
 'perfect',
 'save',
 'ummah',
 'u',
 'coro',
 'patient',
 'classes',
 'month',
 'postpone',
 'government',
 'one',
 'mask',
 'go',
 '2020',
 '95',
 'atrocities',
 'committed',
 'fan',
 'positive',
 'say',
 'someth',
 'adversity',
 'comes',
 'infection',
 'resilience',
 'shared',
 'story',
 'story2',
 'women',
 'young',
 'at',
 'attempt',
 'blame',
 'hapless',
 'humans',
 'shift',
 '911',
 'begging',
 'called',
 'pants',
 'pretty',
 'removed',
 'sure',
 'system',
 'goal',
 'trending',
 'believe',
 'whatever',
 'coronarvirues',
 'updates',
 'owns',
 '236941',
 '4308692',
 'recovered',
 'recoveries',
 'today',
 'catching',
 'fear',
 'players',
 'professional',
 'says',
 'snooker',
 'travel',
 'itll',
 'kill',
 'remains',
 'calling',
 'create',
 'environmen',
 'find',
 'report',
 'start',
 'try',
 'ways',
 'less',
 'days',
 'followers',
 'old',
 'thats',
 'discussing',
 'kills',
 'peroxide',
 'room',
 'tha',
 'wash',
 'bec',
 'dying',
 'entry',
 'hospitals',
 'refused',
 'saw',
 'video',
 'visited',
 'sir',
 'aka',
 'lost',
 'trust',
 'unleashing',
 'whole',
 'world',
 'immune',
 'china',
 'gift',
 'send',
 'cit',
 'folks',
 'mow',
 'nothing',
 'police',
 'see',
 'winning',
 'yep',
 'adding',
 'water',
 'final',
 'wants',
 'عاوزينبديلللخريجين',
 'itself',
 'addimistrstions',
 'bat',
 'bidden',
 'breaking',
 'fund',
 'grant',
 'institutes',
 'provide',
 'virology',
 'attention',
 'freestyle',
 'know',
 'pay',
 'time',
 'took',
 'verse',
 'vir',
 'part',
 'response',
 'bit',
 'control',
 'disappointed',
 'lose',
 'praised',
 'seemed',
 'congress',
 'produced',
 'doctor',
 'highest',
 'humanity',
 'rank',
 'sunset',
 'taking',
 'watch',
 'caring',
 'comm',
 'community',
 'crisis',
 'family',
 'share',
 'us',
 'districts',
 'entering',
 'handled',
 'surrounding',
 'attack',
 'country',
 'also',
 'come',
 '8k',
 'became',
 'bullish',
 'ca',
 'fly',
 'holding',
 'north',
 'poiting',
 'spesk',
 'tightenned',
 'up',
 'hospital',
 'since',
 'cer',
 'infects',
 'public',
 'tell',
 'vertebrate',
 'eat',
 'friends',
 'fucked',
 'ho',
 'used',
 'cosplay',
 'cosplayer',
 'costume',
 'eeyore',
 'home',
 'tiger',
 'quarantine',
 'officials',
 't',
 'truly',
 'anticorona',
 'bring',
 'forget',
 'mall',
 'morning',
 'image',
 'stars',
 'yellow',
 'app',
 'contained',
 'information',
 'mean',
 'all',
 'cannot',
 'justice',
 'kept',
 'truth',
 'every',
 'research',
 '30',
 'bio',
 'lab',
 'new',
 'weapons',
 'ans',
 'argue',
 'covic419',
 'honest',
 'oo',
 'scam',
 'want']
```

and

```
['41',
 '27',
 '12',
 '11',
 '11',
 '11',
 '10',
 '10',
 '10',
 '10',
 '10',
 '6',
 '6',
 '6',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '4',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '2',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1',
 '1']
```

Below a screenshot of the output produced with a `dict(zip(tmp_list[0], tmp_list[1]))`.

[image]

The same happens if I do create the dictionary in this way.

```
words_dict = {}
for i, _ in enumerate(tmp_list[0]):
    words_dict[tmp_list[0][i]] = int(tmp_list[1][i])
```

The only way to circumnavigate the problem is to encode the string in UTF-8 by doing something

```
dict(zip([x.encode('utf-8') for x in tmp_list[0]], tmp_list[1]))
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any other efficient way?
2. Why is that? At the end of the days, the value I'm passing in is a string, so why is the compiler and the dictionary flipping the key with the value?

Comment: my guess would be this happens because all keys must be of the same character set - what happens when you have both key and value be of a different character set (both arabic e.g.)? Does it still include the entry or does it get dropped?

Comment: this works just fine for me. are you on python2? did you try accessing your key in the dictionary? it could just be a printing issue since arabic is a right-to-left language

Comment: @Nullman actually haven't tried to access to the item in all honesty, I inspected only visually and I thought something was wrong from there.

Comment: @Cribber not sure I get what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a problem of output. The Arabic text is displayed [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text), and that affects the entire line apparently, so the dict value is printed left of the key. The dict structure itself is just fine.

Comment: Haven't tried to get access to the key item, so you may be right, but why the apostrophe signalling the string end is also missing?

Comment: Not sure what apostrophe you're talking about…?

Comment: Actually you are right .. I did experiment in generating the dictionary differently and that's when I got it removed. With this implementation ```dict(zip([str(x) for x in tmp_list[0]], [int(x) for x in tmp_list[1]]))```